# Sorting an array of array based on an element of the arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to sort an array of arrays based on any one of the elements selected in the drop down.
The drop down consists of an array of values

```
dropDown = ["Name", "Age", "Country","Points","DOB"];
```

I have a set of arrays in an array like below

```
dataArray = [["01", "Male" , "Mike","24","US',"564","1990-01-07"],["02", "Male","David","25","Canada","450","1989-02-07"],["03", "Female""Lisa","24","US',"450","1990-02-07"],["04", "Male","Smith","23","England',"453","1991-01-07"]]
```

On select of any of the values from the drop down the array dataArray should get sorted. I its in ascending order it should get sorted in descending and vice versa. 
How can i proceed with this using javascript or jquery.The catch here is that my data arrays have two extra values in the beginning.

I tried using this logic

```
function sortData(arrToSort, index, sortAscending, type) {
    if (sortAscending == undefined || sortAscending == '') {
        sortAscending = 'asc';
    }
    var sortdir = (sortAscending === 'asc') ? +1 : -1;
    return arrToSort.sort(function(a, b) {
        a = a[index];
        b = b[index];
        if (type === "int") {
            return (parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt(b, 10)) * sortdir;
        } else if (type === "float") {
            return (parseFloat(a, 10) - parseFloat(b, 10)) * sortdir;
        } else if (type === "string") {
            if (a < b)
                return -1 * sortdir;
            if (a > b)
                return +1 * sortdir;
            return 0;
        } else if (type === "string-ins") {
            a = a.toLowerCase();
            b = b.toLowerCase();
            if (a < b)
                return -1 * sortdir;
            if (a > b)
                return +1 * sortdir;
            return 0;
        } else if (type === "date") {
            return (new Date(a) - new Date(b)) * sortdir;
        }
    });
}

var myArray = [
    ["MVD Title 1","label1","releasedate2","details1"],
    ["DVD Title 2","label3","releasedate1","details1"],
    ["AVD Title 1","label3","releasedate2","details1"],
    ["CVD Title 5","label2","releasedate1","details1"],
    ["DVD Title 3","label1","releasedate1","details1"],
    ["DVD Title 2","label2","releasedaten","detailsn"],
    ["VD Title 2","label1","releasedaten","detailsn"]
];


var sortedRecords = sortData(myArray, 0, 'asc', "string");

console.log(sortedRecords);
```

Comment: Where's your dropdown, where is its event handler? What have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting objects in an array by a field value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript). It's the same for an array of arrays that is sorted by one of the array fields (indices, not properties).

Comment: i tried using this logic but doest seem to work well. Please check the edit in the question

Comment: Works well for me. What exactly happens that is unexpected?

Comment: My arrays data array actually consist of 2 values in the beginning of every array that are not present in the drop down. So ho can i get the index and match it.

Comment: You mean the dropdown's `.selectedIndex` is `0`, but to sort by `Name` you need index `2`? Just add 2 to the number you have!